# Passive Voice when third person is YOU

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, passive-voice, past-perfect, active-voice

What is the passive voice of "you have completed the assignment", is it "The assignment have been completed by you"?

Comment: Just *The assignment **has** been completed*. Usually the whole point about "passive voice" is that ***it doesn't specify the "agent"***.

Answer (score 1):

In the passive voice, the subject becomes "the assignment".  Since this is singular (and not special, like "you"), the correct form of "have" is "has", so it should be:

> The assignment **has been completed** by you.